# Not able to create prod build on ionic with API Level 31 in ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-android

I have changed targetSdk to 31 which giving error with cordova-android 10.1.1 ***Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined***

[AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru642.png)

When I'm adding android:exported=true/false in `<service>`, `<activity>` and `<receiver>`  its giving error ***duplicated with element declared with android:exported in `<service>` or `<receiver>`***

Answer (score 0):

**Keep ionic, angular/react/vue and their plugins updated to make it compatible with latest android version**

Comment: But updation from ionic 3 to ionic 6 will take some time, what if I don't have that much time and I need some solution for now

Comment: Share me your repo link..So I can try to help..